# C++ const * conversion between inherited and base class for a function argument,

Tags: c++

The idea is I have a series of lamda functions stored on a map using a pointer to a static instance as key for any of the inherited classes. I'm unable to write the call properly due a issue converting the pointer type.

I was trying different options and now I'm just stuck trying random stuff having the same error:

```
1>resources\mesh_resource.cpp(28,1): error C2662: 'CResourceType::LParser CResourceType::GetParser(const CResourceType *,std::string)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const CMeshResourceType' to 'CResourceType &'
1>resources\mesh_resource.cpp(28,19): message : Conversion loses qualifiers
1>resources\resource.h(28,11): message : see declaration of 'CResourceType::GetParser' (compiling source file resources\mesh_resource.cpp)
```

Let me show you a some code:

```
class CResourceType {
public:
  typedef std::function<IResource* (const std::string& name)>          LParser;
  static std::unordered_map<const CResourceType*, std::unordered_map<std::string, LParser>>     m_parsers;

{...}

 LParser GetParser(CResourceType const* rt, std::string ext) {...}

{...}
}
```

```
class CMeshResourceType : public CResourceType {
public:
  static CMeshResourceType resource_type;
  IResource* Create(const std::string& name) const override {
    auto parser = GetParser((CResourceType const*)&resource_type, "obj");
    //CMesh* new_mesh = parser(name);
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess I found the issue: `Create()` is `const` but `GetParser()` is non-const. There might be a reason for the latter but it makes the call of `GetParser()` illegal in a `const` method of this class.

Comment: You don't need to cast `&resource_type`. (Note that the problem is `this`, not that.)

Comment: @Scheff It was that!!!!!! Many thanks!! I just added const to GetParser and works fine now.

Comment: If `CResourceType` does not contain any (non-static) data members, you may as well make `GetParser` static (hard to tell, since you did not provide a [mre]).